# Should mod remove answers which doesn't address all sub-questions?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation, deleted-answers

I've [answered](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/459/114) the following question:

- [Effect of the common cold on the immune system](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/452/114)

Sub-questions are:

1. I've heard that once a person catches a cold, his whole immune system becomes weak and is affected
2. In what way does having a cold influence the immune system?
3. If it does weaken it, how can one keep the immune system strong while the person is infected with a cold?

The 1st one is answered by Cause section:

> The common cold is a mild viral infection of the upper respiratory tract (nose, throat, sinuses and upper airways, see below) and over 200 different viral types are associated with colds.

Obviously it address that not whole immune system is affected, but only the upper respiratory tract is infected.

The 2nd question is addressed in Progression section:

> It usually beings with fatigue, a feeling of being chilled, sneezing and a headache. Further symptoms include coughing, sore throat, blocked nose followed by a runny nose, sneezing, cough, a sore throat, and fever which usually resolve in seven to ten days, with some symptoms lasting up to three weeks. The symptoms are believed to be primarily related to the immune response to the virus.
>
> For example when viral infection causes nasal obstruction, the body releasing histamine which increases blood flow to the nose and causes nasal tissue to swell.

The 3rd question is addressed in Prevention section:

> While there's no cure for the common cold, there are the methods which can treat cold symptoms.
>
> The following may help to cope with the symptoms of a cold:
>
> A proper hydration, healthy raw food and the rest is a key for healthy body. So make sure you drink plenty of fluids – water is fine, but warm drinks can be soothing.

Initially my answer was removed by Shog9, because I believe the image had missing reference. I've added the image reference.

Now new moderator (anongoodnurse) found other reason to keep my answer deleted by saying:

> Op's question's were: "...once a person catches a cold, his whole immune system becomes weak and is affected. In what way... ...how can one keep the immune system strong while the person is infected with a cold?" Your answer is a general treatise on the cols. Can you please address the OP's question with the bulk of your answer? anongoodnurse

My answer is bulk, because the are many questions to be addressed by OP.

> how can one keep the immune system strong while the person is infected with a cold?

I've posted a long list of things which help to cope with the symptoms of a cold (which answer that).

So I really don't understand why my answer is still kept in deleted state.

I believe this answer answers the question and it should be undeleted.

And further improvements should be done by commenting on that answer (now in undeleted state it's not possible to even comment what's wrong, only moderators can, so it's like one-way communication). Secondly other users cannot suggest anything else (because they don't see the answer and the commenting feature is blocked), so I'm forced to do the changes to my content indicated only by one person, otherwise my answer won't be published. This is how it should work?

In that situation and similar others, I fail to see how the site can be moderated by community.

> At Stack Exchange, we believe moderation starts with the community itself.

Answer (score 3):

The original question(s):

> I've heard that once a person catches a cold, his whole immune system becomes weak and is affected. In what way does having a cold influence the immune system?  ...If it does weaken it, how can one keep the immune system strong while the person is infected with a cold?

Your answer starts by explaining what the common cold is and what areas of the body it affects (The OP didn't ask this.) You state

> "Pure immune function is also a risk for developing such disease (such malnutrition or lack of sleep)."

I'm not sure I know what that means, and I *should*. Does it mean that a pure immune function puts you at risk for malnutrition and sleep deprivation? Or does it mean, a bad immune function puts you at risk for malnutrition and sleep deprivation? Or do you mean malnutrition and sleep deprivation make your immune system unpure? If so, how does this relate to immunity when infected by a cold virus?

You then go on to give another long paragraph of what happens with a cold, none of which answers the question. You advise on *decreasing the symptoms* of the common cold (with some unsupported claims thrown in). *That is not the same as building up immunity.*

Finally you finish it up by adding links.

None of this addresses the OP's question: does having a cold really decrease immune functions? If it does, how can one boost immunity?

It was deleted by Shog9. After deletion, I basically gave you the same advice I'm giving you here.

> Op's question's were: "...once a person catches a cold, his whole immune system becomes weak and is affected. In what way... ...how can one keep the immune system strong while the person is infected with a cold?" Your answer is a general treatise on the cols [sic]. Can you please address the OP's question with the bulk of your answer? –  anongoodnurse♦ 23 hours ago

Answers that do not answer the question will be down voted, commented upon, or deleted. Any of which should tell you that there's a problem with your answer.

One hour ago, you stated you improved your answer. I still see no answer. That is why the request to undelete was declined.

> At Stack Exchange, we believe moderation starts with the community itself.

Yes. And Shog9 posted about what kind of answers are desired on SE sites. He has been a strong proponent of self-moderation. That does not mean *no moderation*. I did not undelete your answer because you failed to address the question.

Comment: Thanks. I've addressed your concerns regarding my answer and flagged for review.

Comment: @kenorb - I could not see an edit; the last edit I see occurred on April 20th. Try as I might, I can't find a more recent edit. Are you thinking perhaps of a different question? If you're certain it's *this* question, re-flagging an unchanged answer does not change the outcome.

Comment: There are 4 revisions, [last one was done 7 hours ago](http://health.stackexchange.com/posts/459/revisions).

Comment: @kenorb - I'm sorry, that was my mistake; please forgive me. Yes, I did see this revision.  I read through your Wikipedia references supporting your initial statement about immunity and was unable to find support for your assertion (and the articles are *long*.) I even followed one link on malnutrition and immunity; that link was for HIV in malnourished sub-Saharan Africa. It's true that you did revise your answer, but it remains, in *essence*, the same as before. Did you receive my invitation to discuss this in a private room? I didn't receive a reply. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if we're talking about the same answer (about [cold](http://health.stackexchange.com/a/459/114)?). HIV related is completely [different answer](http://health.stackexchange.com/a/427/114). In cold answer I didn't find any links to HIV. I didn't receive any invitation link.

Comment: @kenorb - Yes, this time we are (sorry about last time). The two links in the second line are to Wikipedia (is that correct?) I read through them to find support for the statement that sleep deprivation and malnourishment make us susceptible to the common cold. I also followed their link. (HIV) I will try to ping you again.